# How can i run a task Given a Period of Time?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

How can i run a task Given a Period of Time? I have thought that this task is to refresh the user's current position. Is this possible in ios5?

thanx for reading

Comment: quite a vague question what is Given Period of time.
if you want to schedule a task after like 2 sec.. use Nstimer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refresh current location, use CLLocationManager and request significant location changes. This saves battery life.

Otherwise, your question doesn’t make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

following code may to helpful for the selecting method repeat the method.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(gotoshop) withObject:nashville afterDelay:1.0];
```

and method is

```
-(void)gotoshop{
// your code goes here..
}
```